# Tactile button switch footprint in KiCAD

Tags: switches, kicad, button, footprint

I want to use this tactile switch in my PCB design:
https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2002271735_XKB-Connectivity-TS-1101-C-W_C318938.pdf

As you can see in the document, the distance between the edges of the pins is 8mm.
I searched for all the available footprints in KiCad's library, but I did not find a single one with these dimensions.

This looks remarkable to me, as this tactile switch is a common one. Am I missing something?

Comment: If it's not there, it's not there - not much to say about it. KiCad library is remarkable, but you still have to design your footprints. You can design this one and contribute to the library though!

Comment: Making your own part footprints is a standard part of PCB design; the built-in libraries will never have every part out there. Go ahead and make your own, you'll need to get practice anyway.

Comment: If it's not there, it's not there - not much to say about it.   The same is true for any SCH Cad program out there.  Newish users often don't realize that making PCB & SCH parts comes with the job.  Once you make a few, you will likely find that you would rather make (or customize) all of your parts to suit your setup.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In the Kicad v6.0.10 PCB library there is a part (footprint) that is very close to this tactile PB switch.
It could be modified slightly or possibly even used as is.
See:
SW_Tactile_SPST_NO_Straight_CK_PTS636Sx25SMTRLFS

Here is a view with approx dimensions added.

[image]